# quering oracle view with hibernate everytime results to null

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

i've built an entitybean using the hibernate tools from an existing oracle view.
The problem is that every query results to NULL.

I have searched the web to find a solution but i didn't find one.

I've tried something like this:

```
public static List<View> getBillRecord()
  {
    Query query = em.createQuery("from View where column=123");
    return query.getResultList();
  }
```

The resulting query seems to be ok when i switch on 
`<property name="show_sql">true</property>` in hibernate.cfg.xml.

Any suggestions/hints?

Comment: what does the query do when you execute it directly against the database, such as in sql developer?

Comment: when i execute the query in my sql developer it works as expected.

Comment: What occurs if you executed it as a `NamedNativeQuery`?

Comment: do you mapped `View` class to database table correctly?

Comment: I have only NamedQuery or NativeQuery but not NamedNativeQuery methods.

Comment: as i said, i have reverse engineerd the view by using the reveng tool from hibernate in eclipse

Comment: please go to sqlfiddle and post your schema.

Comment: When i last time used hibernate tools, they can generate code suitable for hibernate (org.hibernate.annotations.*), not for JPA (javax.persistence.*).

Answer (score 0):

This should function as expected:

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "findViewByColumn",
    query = "select * from view v where v.column = :column",
        resultClass = View.class
    )
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "View")
public class View implements java.io.Serializable {  
...  
}
```

Comment: hi, i tried your solution but the problem still exists. the list is empty

Comment: @user1803076 is the List empty or is it null?  That is a key difference.

Comment: the size is 1 but the elements are null

Comment: @user1803076 I see can you please recreate your schema and a few sample records at sqlfiddle and post them here in your original question so we can further help the debug process?

Comment: @user1803076 Ok.  We will still need a sql fiddle to further debug this problem.

Comment: is it important to say that the generated view consists of two classes view.class and viewid.class because a view has no primary key?

Comment: @user1803076 a view is a virtual function and executes a brand new query every time it is run.  Conversely a materialized view holds the precomputed values for a query.  The table created for a materialized view can have a primary key.  Perhaps this is what you wanted from the start?

Comment: no, i want query a simple view. i have tested around a little bit more. and i found out that a your example works well on a view which only consists of two joined tables but not my real view . my real view cosists of serveral subqueries and views. but i cant post the real view here.

Comment: @user1803076 you can post a view that looks identical to it.  I usually use Cats,Dogs, and Vets.  If you cannot give us enough information to work with we will have to vote to close the question.

Comment: hi, i found out, that querying a view via hibernate results to NULL if the view contains NUMERIC AND/OR DATE columns.

Comment: @user1803076 I would highly suggest posting that answer here and accepting it.

Comment: Now my problem is sloved. when hibernate creates an entitybean from a database view it creates an id object containing all attributes of the view as primary-key, so if i search for a value of a column NO column should be NULL. If so, the result is NULL. my so solution is to create a disabled primary key on the view. after that you can reverse engineer the view again with hibernate and everthing is fine.